# Deletion progress status

Tags: linux, sles

In our case, we have some files in the directory /root/Documents/folder1 in which we want to delete the files which start with sam*, we have proceeded with the command

```
rm sam*
```

which is working fine but we need to know which file is being deleted during the deletion progress.

Comment: Do you need to know as it's being deleted or when it actually is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the verbose parameter `-v`:

From `man rm`:

> ```
>    -v, --verbose  
>           explain what is being done
> ```

Usage:

```
$ rm -v wget-log
removed 'wget-log'
```